# Error in IF NOT EXISTS sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm just trying out some Python3-sqlite3 code when the following error occured

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect("../db/mydb.db")
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE SCHEDULER IF NOT EXISTS (SNO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, STRTIME TEXT, ENDTIME TEXT, MODE TEXT)''')
conn.execute('''INSERT INTO SCHEDULER VALUES (1, 'XXXX', 'XXXX', 'MODE')''')
conn.close()
```

I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "db.py", line 4, in 
>       conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE SCHEDULER IF NOT EXISTS(SNO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, STRTIME TEXT, ENDTIME TEXT, MODE TEXT)''')
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "IF": syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF NOT EXISTS` must come earlier, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SCHEDULER  (SNO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, STRTIME TEXT, ENDTIME TEXT, MODE TEXT);
```

If this still doesn't work, then your SQLite version is *really* old (older than version 3.3.0).

Comment: This worked, thanks. I was following an old tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

SCHEDULER being the name of your table, it needs to be in quote like "SCHEDULER" IF